Kotlin reflection - retrieve property if it exists
I'd like to retrieve a property if the referenced object has one.   (I have a more complex use case, but this demonstrates the problem nicely).  It appears, the only way to do this is by breaking variance.   Is there a safe way to do this?
fun <T : Any> T.valueFor(name: String): Any? {
    val clazz = this::class as KClass<T> // <-- unsafe to get around variance
    val prop = clazz.memberProperties.firstOrNull { name == it.name }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("No property called '$name'")
    return prop.get(this) // <-- compile error here without the cast
}

This is an excellent discussion on the topic:
Kotlin property delegation without reflection
I could fix this by passing in a KClass of the desired type, but the whole idea is to write a general method where the type isn't known in advance.   I'm trying to think of a counter example where this would be a bad thing especially considering that our data models are flat (without inheritance).
@Test
fun `retrieve property`() {
    open class Animal(val color: String)
    class Dog(val name: String, color: String) : Animal(color)

    val dog = Dog("Rocky", "Yellow")
    assertThat(dog.valueFor("name")).isEqualTo(dog.name)
    assertThat(dog.valueFor("color")).isEqualTo(dog.color)

    val animal: Animal = dog
    assertThat(animal.valueFor("name")).isEqualTo(dog.name)
    assertThat(animal.valueFor("color")).isEqualTo(dog.color)

    val diffAnimal = Animal("Orange")
    assertThrows<IllegalArgumentException> { diffAnimal.valueFor("name") }
    assertThat(diffAnimal.valueFor("color")).isEqualTo(diffAnimal.color)
}


Probably worth adding my usual warning: in Kotlin, reflection is a code smell.  While powerful, it's slow, long-winded, fragile, ugly, insecure, and converts compile errors into runtime exceptions that are harder to test and fix.  Reflection is needed for frameworks, plugins, build tools, and similar — but for normal application coding, there's nearly always a better approach.  (Over-use of reflection seems to be most common in folks with a background in dynamic languages such as JavaScript; it's not such a good fit for statically-typed languages.)

For example, why not put your ‘name’ and ‘color’ properties into an interface that some subclasses of Animal can implement?  Then you can simple use an ‘is ’ check, and let the compiler smart-cast the result so you can then just use ‘.name’ in the normal way?

By changing return prop.get(this) to return prop.getter.call(this) or the short form return prop.call(this), you can remove the cast as KClass<T>.
In your example code, <T : Any> T.valueFor can be replaced with just Any.valueFor.
While the below changes are solving the issues with your example code, there might be issues using this with more complex cases.
Rewritten code
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

fun Any.valueFor(name: String): Any? { // changed to Any.valueFor
    val clazz = this::class // removed cast
    val prop = clazz.memberProperties.firstOrNull { it.name == name }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("No property called '$name'")
    return prop.call(this) // Use `call` instead of `get`
}

Update
Not in the question, but adding code for setters as well.
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty1
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

fun Any.setValueFor(name: String, value: Any) {
    val clazz = this::class
    val prop = clazz.memberProperties.firstOrNull { it.name == name }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("No property called '$name'")

    if (prop !is KMutableProperty1<*, *>) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Property '$name' is not mutable")
    }
    prop.setter.call(this, value)
}

Code is tested on my computer.

I like it.  Thank you!
